# Nginx SSL pass-thru not working with a REST web service

Tags: web-services, ssl, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to do load balancing on 3 SSL enabaled REST webservice instances using Nginx.

I need to use SSL pass-thru in my case.

I have followed https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-nginx-ssltls-passthru-with-tcp-load-balancing/

and 
https://serversforhackers.com/c/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru

but i am not getting default json on hitting the load balancer endpoint.

I am getting output as shown in image for all type of request.

[image]

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, you have enabled HTTPS on Nginx but your hosted REST webservice is not listening properly for HTTPS requests thus 5x response returned by Nginx not by your hosted webservice.

Have you enabled SSL engine in Nginx?   also please share Nginx configuration file.

Comment: I have checked the response was only received when the web service is running otherwise i wan not getting those random characters.

Answer (score 0):

While following https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-nginx-ssltls-passthru-with-tcp-load-balancing/ I found that
    **proxy_ssl  on;** was missing. Below stream configuration worked perfectly and we need to access Nginx server on **http** not **https** protocol but port used was 8443. I need to figure out why its not working on **https** protocol.

```
stream {
    upstream apiservers {
        192.168.1.2:8443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
        192.168.1.3:8443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
        192.168.1.4:8443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
    }

    server {
        listen 8443;
        proxy_ssl  on;
        proxy_pass apiservers;
        proxy_next_upstream on;
    }
}
```